# Java sharing variable between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, static, shared

I have a multi-thread program and I want to share this variable 
1st thread

```
public static volatile Message recievedMessages;
```

between threads. On the thread it is declared I want to be able to set the variable value multiple times and in the other thread I just want to be able to get the variable's value.
What should be my approach?

2nd thread

```
SSLServer.recievedMessages.getMsgContent();
```

which gives me java null pointer exception, the string is not defined on the second thread

edit:Also it's worth mentioning that the second class is a java swing gui

Comment: Should the thread be notified whenever the value of `recievedMessages` has changed (e.g. execute some code on change)? Or should it just always see the newest version of `recievedMessages`, but not do anything on change?

Comment: the second thread should only see the value, it doesn't ever change it.

Comment: Answering your question: it should only see the latest version.
Also I have provided a code snippet from the other class

Comment: "it should only see the latest version".

Really? Even when the latest version is `null`?